# Como utilizar a função bcrypt do laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, aplicação-web, bcrypt, password

Possuo um arquivo `.php` na pasta public do Laravel e por motivos maiores não posso criar um controller dele. Porém preciso utilizar a função `bcrypt` para gerar a senha uma senha criptografada, só que não consigo utilizar essa função em um arquivo `.php` puro na pasta `public`.

Como posso utilizar essa função?

Comment: É um erro utilizar código na pasta public porque precisa fazer assim.???

Comment: O PHP tem nativamente o `password_hash` que porta BCrypt (e Argon2i no PHP 7.2, ainda em Beta).

Answer (score 2):

Para garantir que fique exatamente igual o bcrypt do gerado pelo laravel, faá um controler para chamar um ajax, uma espécie de webservice, esse controler vocë terá a função para retornar

```
public function getBcrypt($secret) {

   return bcrypt('secret');

}
```

no seu arquivo php você pode chamar essa url via curl ou ajax, vai gerar o código criptografado perfeitamente.